# Optional test cases in Django

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

We have a moderately large test suite for business logic and this completes within a few seconds. We're running this as a condition to commit (a hook that must pass) and that has been working well to block the most stupid mistakes from making it off my machine.

We've recently started adding end-to-end frontend tests with webdriver. Some of these tests pass over third party integrations. The tests are useful but they're really slow and require a network connection.

We also have some logic tests that are extremely long that are commented out (yeah!) unless we suspect something wrong.

Is there a sensible way to split these slow tests out so they only run when we specifically want them to and not every time you run `./manage.py test`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use default Django test runner there is no simple way of doing what you want. Maybe rearranging the test directory structure so you could call `./manage.py test path/to/directory_with/webtests` or `./manage.py test path/to/directory_with_fast_tests`

Another solution is using `pytest` [Custom Markers](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html)

As Documentation states:

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.webtest
def test_send_http():
    pass # perform some webtest test for your app
```

[Register](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#registering-markers) custom marker:

```
# content of pytest.ini
[pytest]
markers =
    webtest: mark a test as a webtest.
```

Then you just run `pytest -v -m webtest` and only marked tests will be executed.